# How to put a hex value into a 24 bit struct

Tags: c, struct, hex

So i have 2 structs:

```
struct cmd {
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t b;
    uint8_t c;
}; 

typedef struct someName{
    uint8_t size;
    struct cmd cmdID;
} someName_t;
```

And i got a `char res[0]` containing the string `"0xabc"`.

This `0xabc` need to be put inside the `cmd` struct.

But the problem is `0xabc` is 12 bit (`1010 1011 1100`) so if i put this into the struct with only `uint8_t a` and `uint8_t b` it will work because it will "fit" into 16 bits. But i got `uint8_t a`, `uint8_t b` and `uint8_t c` so 24 bits and that is my problem..

I tried:

```
someName_t msg;
sscanf(res[0], "0x%x", &(msg.cmdID));
```

But this does not work. This does work however if i remove the `uint8_t c` variable from the struct because it then fits inside the remaining 16 bits..

So how can i get the value `"0xabc"` into this (24bit) struct without adjusting the struct.

Comment: Please clarify the question ... the string "0xabc" is not 16 bits. It's 5 bytes (plus terminating 0). The value 0xabc is not restricted to 16 bits either. And it seems noone understands what do you want to put in the `cmd` struct

Comment: The value 0xabc = 1010 1011 1100 wich are 12 bits so if i put this into the struct with only uint8_t a and uint8_t  b it will work because it will "fit" into 16 bits. But i got uint8_t a, uint8_t b and uint8_t c so 24 bits and that is my problem..

Comment: If something fits in 16 bits then it definitely fits in 24 too ... I still don't see the problem

Comment: Yeah thats where you are wrong.. If i use uint8_t a and uint8_t b like i said and read it back i get 0xabc, adding the uint8_t c i get 0x2ce470

Comment: Now I understand ... can you update the question too?

Comment: This is very unclear.

Comment: `char res[0]` is not legal, arrays cannot be zero-sized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control of your input format, i.e. you can guarantee it will always be something like `0xabc`, then you can try:

```
const char input[] = "0xabc";
uint32_t tmp;
sscanf(input, "0x%x", &tmp);

struct cmd cmdid;
cmdid.a = (tmp & 0xFF0000U) >> 16;
cmdid.b = (tmp & 0xFF00U) >> 8;
cmdid.c = (tmp & 0xFFU);
```

Comment: Looks like what i need!. It will indeed always be 0x..., the only problem is that i dont want to go "inside" the cmd struct. But seems like i have no other option..

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing `struct cmd` to:

```
struct cmd {
    unsigned int c:4;
    unsigned int b:4;
    unsigned int a:4;
};
```

But YMMV depending on compiler. Works OK on MSVC++ 2010.

Comment: True and the issue is related to 24 bits because this works also:

    uint16_t a:8;
    uint16_t b:8;
    uint16_t c:8;